# In the "rbenv-rehash" bash script, what does "-e* | -- ) break ;;" do?

Tags: bash

I'm learning about bash scripting now, and studying the shims in my rbenv `.shims` folder.  I noticed they're all completely identical, and they all contain the following line of code:

```
-e* | -- ) break ;;
```

[Source](https://github.com/rbenv/rbenv/blob/1c772d5ff21bbee52e0c6cdf128c5cffaf8feea8/libexec/rbenv-rehash#L52)

Questions-

1. What is the `-e` flag here, and why does it have an asterisk immediately after?  I know that the `-e` flag inside a square bracket statement means `if a file exists by the name of ____`, but that doesn't appear to be what's going on here.
2. Why is the output of `-e*` being piped to `--`?  What is `--` doing here?
3. Why is there a closing paren with no opening paren?

Full context of the shim file is here:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
set -e
[ -n "$RBENV_DEBUG" ] && set -x

program="${0##*/}"
if [ "$program" = "ruby" ]; then
  for arg; do
    case "$arg" in
    -e* | -- ) break ;;
    */* )
      if [ -f "$arg" ]; then
        export RBENV_DIR="${arg%/*}"
        break
      fi
      ;;
    esac
  done
fi

export RBENV_ROOT="/Users/richiethomas/.rbenv"
exec "/usr/local/Cellar/rbenv/1.1.2/libexec/rbenv" exec "$program" "$@"
```

Comment: https://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/bash/manual/bash.html#index-case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `case` statement in most of the shells including `bash` support glob expressions of the type you've shown. You need to understand that the strings within the `(..)` or `..)` are *never* evaluated as commands but only as glob expressions. The `-e*` is an expression that could match zero or more arguments after `-e` i.e. `-error` or `-e123` or `-e45#@`

You could simply see this in action by executing a trivial script

```
set -- '-e' '-error' '-e123' '-e45#@' '--'
for arg; do
    case "$arg" in
        -e* ) printf '%s\n' 'glob expression -e* matched for '"$arg"'' ;;
         *  ) printf '%s\n' 'no match for '"$arg"'' ;;
    esac
done
```

Also, the part `-e* | -- )` is not a shell pipeline, but part of the `case` syntax for specifying multiple patterns. The part

```
-e* | -- ) break ;;
```

simply means that, if you see an argument that starts with `-e` or see `--` do the common action of breaking out of the `for` loop.

The leading `(` for enclosing the patterns is purely optional in `bash` and in any POSIX conforming shell. So `-e* | -- )` or `( -e* | -- )` are both equally valid.

Comment: So for this RBENV script as a whole, is it accurate to say that the sole purpose of the conditional is to check if the calling program is `ruby` and (if it is) to a) break out of the `for` loop immediately if the user passes `--` or `-e`, and b) to set the `RBENV_DIR` environment variable if the user passes a filepath?